# Getting an exception with wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element) method

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use chrome driver for selenium . While all other operations work okay, when I use the below code I am getting exception. The element does exist and driver is not null. If I comment out the this call (and replace with sleep), the test moves fine. Any idea what could be the reason for the failure.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.isDisplayed(RemoteWebElement.java:320)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:51)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.isDisplayed(Unknown Source)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(ExpectedConditions.java:315)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$100(ExpectedConditions.java:44)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:301)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:298)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:248)

Comment: What OS are you using?  Are you using compatible versions of `chrome` and `chromedriver` (e.g. v77 is current)?

Comment: I am using chrome 77 and selenium 4.0.0-alpha-2. Have also downloaded the supporting chromedriver for chrome77.

Comment: I just tried downgrading selenium to 3.141 and getting the same exception. Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Can you provide the (minimal amount of) HTML to reproduce behavior?

Comment: What is `element` and how is it decorated?

Comment: Here is the PageObjectClass
`public class RelatedPage extends UiComponent {
    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[@id='related']")
    private WebElement relatedTab;
public void clickRelatedTab() {
waitForExistenceofElement(relatedTab,10);
        relatedTab.click();
    }
 public void waitForExistenceofElement(WebElement element, int timeout) {
 WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driverUtil.getWebDriver(), timeout);
       webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    }`

Comment: and UIComponent is : 
 protected final DriverUtil driverUtil;

    public UiComponent(DriverUtil driverUtil) {
        this.driverUtil = driverUtil;
        PageFactory.initElements(driverUtil.getWebDriver(), this);

    }

Comment: Also, to note is that if I do not use FindBy and instead directly use 'By related = By.xpath(//a[@id='related']) and then waitForVisibility of "related", I do not hit this exception. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Please update your post with the additional information, instead of putting it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading selenium to 3.0.1 solved the issue.

Comment: Downgrading, especially to a version that is so far outdated, is almost never the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

This error might have been caused by the chromedriver. I faced the same issue with chrome driver version 77.x and then issue was resolved when I downgraded chromedriver  to version 76.x. Refer below page:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3123